# Trying to split a string into a list, reverse the order of the list, and then print out a string of the reversed string

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a string that I split into a list, and am able to successfully print it out correctly in reversed order. However, when I join the list back into a string, it just stays as a list. Where is my join function going wrong?

My code:

```
sample_string = 'Hello Dragon and Snakie'

words = sample_string.split(" ")
reordered = str(words[::-1])
final = "".join(reordered)
print(final)
```

expected: Snakie and Dragon Hello

actual: ['Snakie', 'and', 'Dragon', 'Hello']

Thank You

Comment: Your output is actually a string--a string with brackets so it looks like a list. `reordered` is a string, not a list. Just take out the `str` function and add a space for your `join` method to space out the words.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replace this line:

```
reordered = str(words[::-1])
```

With:

```
reordered = words[::-1]
```

Because you make the list into a string with a list in it, so it won't join for the list.

And also replace this line:

```
final = "".join(reordered)
```

With:

```
final = " ".join(reordered)
```

Since you wanna join with space.